# Flanking with tiny reach creatures

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, flanking

Does a creature with a tiny size, and a reach of 5, sharing the space of the enemy provide flanking? Example down below. X being the enemy, T is the tiny creature and Me is well, me.

[X][X][X]

[X][T][X]

[X][X][X]

....[Me]

Comment: Is this a single Huge (3x3 / 15ft) enemy, or just one medium-sized (1x1 / 5ft) enemy that's in the same space as the tiny creature? I guess it might be the same question either way, I'm just trying to better understand the diagram.

Comment: Diagram is a huge creature, but it's just an example.

Comment: Could the question clarify whether the it's asking about *Me* getting flanking from *T*, *T* getting flanking from *Me*, or both?

Comment: @HeyICanChan the title talks about flanking _with_ tiny creatures, the body asks if the tiny creature _provides_ flanking, I think it's clear enough?

Comment: @Zachiel Yeah, I know, but the two ideas are *so* intertwined I really would like the question to make it 100% crystal  clear that the Tiny creature receiving the flanking bonus is not an issue. (I deleted my answer because, while it addressed the *absolute* letter of the question, I got hung up when I tried taking it a step further into the other—and, you're right, perhaps unimportant—direction. I mean, I figured anybody finding this question would want to know if it worked the other way, too!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, the tiny ally would  not (in this case) provide flanking.

Core Rulebook page 197 wrote:

> Flanking
>
> When making a melee attack, you get a +2 flanking bonus if your opponent is threatened by another enemy character or creature on its opposite border or opposite corner.
>
> When in doubt about whether two characters flank an opponent in the middle, trace an imaginary line between the two attackers’ centers. If the line passes through opposite borders of the opponent’s space (including corners of those borders), then the opponent is flanked.
>
> Exception: If a flanker takes up more than 1 square, it gets the flanking bonus if any square it occupies counts for flanking. 
>   Only a creature or character that threatens the defender can help an attacker get a flanking bonus.
>
> Creatures with a reach of 0 feet can’t flank an opponent.

In your example, the question becomes: Is the tiny ally's position on an opposite border of the opponent's space from the space you occupy?

Since each ally is roughly positioned within 90 degrees of separation from the enemy's perspective (instead of the approximate 180 degrees required), it's not difficult enough for the enemy to keep tabs on their positions to warrant the normal flanking bonus.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping that I had missed some errata, faq or dev comment on it. Thanks!